# How to get inline results in a worksheet in Eclipse/Scala-IDE on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, worksheet, scala-ide

I've got the Scala-IDE installed on my Mac and on my pc with Ubuntu 12.04. In there I created a project, with a package and in there a worksheet. On my mac, the worksheet shows results of every line on the same line on the right. For example:

```
package mypackage
object myworksheet {
    println("Hello World!")                                  > Hello World!
}
```

On Ubuntu however, I do not see the result on the right. I've tried making changes in the worksheet and saving it, but it makes no difference.

Does anybody know how I can get these inline results on my Ubuntu machine as well?

Comment: it works on my ubuntu machine. hard to say, why it's not working without further information. if you installed scala IDE via 'install new software' in already existing eclipse, you may have to install the scala worksheet plugin manually. also be sure, that the worksheet is opened with "scala script editor" and not "scala editor" (right click on file -> open with).

Comment: @3x14159265 - I installed Scala-IDE by downloading the latest binary from http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html , unpacking it, and double clicking the binary in the eclipse folder. Therefore I unfortunately can't do a right click > open with scala script editor. In the Scala-IDE I also tried doing File>Open file... but there is no option to choose a scala script editor or even a scala editor. Any other ideas?

Comment: I only have scala IDE installed as eclipse extension... don't know if it exists in scala-ide prebuild package, but at menu section 'help->install new software' you can see the already installed plugins and check if the worksheets plugin exists...

Comment: @3x14159265 - I searched for "Scala worksheet", found an extension and tried to install it, but it says a newer version is already installed. Any other tips would be highly appreciated! (oh, and btw: would you or anybody else know a good Scala forum?)

Comment: faced the same issue , problem with space in project name , mean my existing project name is "First World" , so in this case it is not working , after that i changed it to "FirstWorld" and now it is working

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, adding -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 to eclipse.ini fixed the issue.

For more details look at answer to the question: [Results encoding in Scala Worksheet Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470050/results-encoding-in-scala-worksheet-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: You can also do this in [Eclipse Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18947396/458193) (this helped me on OS X).

Answer (score 10):

Having a space in the Project name was the problem for me.
Creating a new project without the space resolved it.

See this answer [New scala worksheets not evaluated in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230840/new-scala-worksheets-not-evaluated-in-eclipse/30999391#30999391)

Comment: please quote the most relevant content of the link

Comment: @CodeiSir not sure what you mean by this, the name of the link is the most relevant information. Thanks

Comment: That worked for me, hit F2 over the project name with a space in it in eclipse and took out space.  Then went over to worksheet, saved it, and the worksheet executed.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer to your question-

I agree that the project name should not contain a space, you can also
get Inline Result in `Scala Worksheet`

New Project < Scala Project < Type a Name < Finish 
GO to src < Right CLick < Scala Worksheet

P.S. Also here you don't need to `Run` (just hit Ctrl+S to save) also you don't need to append `extends App` to the `obj worksheet name`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the scala installation to default version.

Follow these steps:

1. Project -> Right click -> Properties -> Scala Compiler
2. Click Scala Installation drop down.
3. Select "Latest 2.12 bundle (dynamic)" in drop down

[image]