# Results encoding in Scala Worksheet Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, scala, character-encoding

How can I change charset encoding for results in the Worksheet in Eclipse?

```
object workbook1 {
"cyrillic A is: " + "А"  //> res0: String("cyrylic A is: Рђ") = cyrylic A is: Рђ
}
```

Editor's encoding is UTF-8. Results are printed right into editors window, but the encoding of results is different. This is in Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many thanks to @Excelan's original question and solution as it definitely got me pointed in the right direction!

I was experiencing this problem using the Scala Eclipse IDE when working with new projects I created, but was not experiencing the problem when using imported projects. Once I saw Excelan's comment about the encoding I started poking around, you can change the Eclipse default text file encoding for all projects in the Preferences like so:

```
 Open Preferences
 Expand the "General" menu.
 Select the "Workspace" menu.
 Change "Text file encoding" option from Default to Other and select UTF-8.
```

Once I followed those steps, closed and reopened eclipse. Every new worksheet created after that works just fine!

[image: Screencap of preferences]

To change the settings on a project level, right click the project and select properties. The text file encoding is found under the "Resources" menu.

To change the settings for a single file, right click the file and select properties.
The text file encoding is found under the "Resources" menu.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with invisible results on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because JVM handles input strings as encoded with system default (cp1251 in my case)

You should say to JVM that input strings are in UTF-8
To do this, put into your **eclipse.ini**:

**-Dfile.encoding=UTF8**

If there is better (project local) solution, please let me know.
This seems to be Windows-only related question.