# New scala worksheets not evaluated in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, scala

I am using Scala on Eclipise IDE on Linux. I am facing issues with the evaluation of the new worksheets. Expressions in new worksheets being created do not get evaluated and inline results are not being shown.

However, the old worksheets are still work fine and the expressions get evaluated properly and the results are displayed inline.

I did try the following suggestion from this stackoverflow thread: [Getting Inline Results in Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995704/how-to-get-inline-results-in-a-worksheet-in-eclipse-scala-ide-on-ubuntu-12-04)

However, this doesn't work as well. Could someone suggest a solution for this? Why are the new worksheets not working while the old worksheets are still working fine?

Comment: Any errors or warnings?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 8):

I was going mad... Ubuntu 15.04 - Eclipse Scala IDE 4.1  (based on Luna 4.4.2)

Worksheets evaluation worked in some projects only.
Finally realized that if the project name contains a space, the worksheet won't evaluate.

Hope this helps.