# Scala worksheet not getting evaluated on changing scala compiler version

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have just started with `scala` and I am using [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) to run my scripts.

I created some basic `scala worksheets` which compiles and shows the output on the right side in the IDE.

The default scala version that came built-in with Scala IDE is `2.12.2`

I decided to move to `scala version 2.11.8`(which also came built in with the IDE) after facing some dependency issues.

I changed the `Scala Installation` to "`Fixed Scala Installation: 2.11.8(built-in)"` by *right-clicking project->Properties->Scala Compiler*

As soon as I changed the installation my all worksheets stopped working. They are not getting evaluated. They are also not getting saved. I saved the scripts multiple times but the files are still showing unsaved changes(`*`). I also restarted Scala IDE, but the problem didn't solve.

Is there any thing else that I need to change? What wrong am I doing?
Also the project name does not contain any SPACE(suggest as a possible cause for this problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230840/new-scala-worksheets-not-evaluated-in-eclipse/30999391#30999391) answer)

The problem is occurring only when I change Scala version

Answer (score 3):

Having a space in the Project name was the problem for me. Creating a new project without the space resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems the worksheet only works with default Scala version in Scala IDE. I have tried uninstall the default Scala version and install a different Scala version, say 2.11.8. I can do that, but I won't be able to uninstall the Scala Worksheet and reinstall another version. The IDE will nevertheless stick with the original scala IDE build version and don't think you can install a version earlier than that. So I am stuck. The uninstall and install is done by clicking `Help -> Install New Software...`

Since i need to install different Scala version in Eclipse anyway, I just go download and install a bare-bones version Eclipse and install the Scala version and the Scala Worksheet version I want. The repository I use is `Scala IDE - http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e46/scala211/stable/site` for Scala version 2.11.8.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

1. Project -> Right click -> Properties -> Scala Compiler
2. Click Scala Installation drop down.
3. Select "Latest 2.12 bundle (dynamic)" in drop down

[image]