# Scala worksheet in Eclipse Luna not working

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, sbt, eclipse-luna, scala-ide

This [past post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995704/how-to-get-inline-results-in-a-worksheet-in-eclipse-scala-ide-on-ubuntu-12-04) offers two solutions. I tried both but there was no change.

I have a Scala project that I downloaded from Github.
It is built by SBT.
So I followed these instructions:
http://scalatutorials.com/beginner/2013/07/18/getting-started-with-sbt/

I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1., on Ubuntu 14.04.

I added Scala IDE plugin together with Scala Worksheet plugin:
http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html

Eclipse recognizes `.scala` files but does not evaluate or recognize worksheet (`.cs`) files (there is no highlighting in `.cs` files, as if they were just text).

I have tried to change and save `.cs` files but nothing happens.

If I use the Scala interpreter view and sends there the text from a worksheet file, it is interpreted.

When I try to create a new Scala worksheet project, this option does not appear among the Scala project types.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-scala-worksheet.html

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem (worksheet won't evaluate) in 4.4.1 on Oracle Linux. I don't have an answer for me yet, but your problem might be the worksheet extension. You've reported worksheet.`cs` as the name, while my install creates worksheets as worksheet.`sc` (note the different extension). If that isn't a typo in your question, you might try renaming your worksheet.