# Scala worksheet not evaluating the REPL and printing the result on right side

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I am learning spark and using eclipse ScalaIDE, in which i am creating a new worksheet.

As the worksheet in scala is evaluated when we save the file and result are printed in the right side, but this is not happening when i make some changes in the worksheet.

Here is my scala worksheet:

```
object LearingScalaWorkshheet1 {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  val hello: String = "Hello World!"
  println(hello)
}
```

Is there anything which i am missing?

Comment: Maybe you have a space in your project name? (From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995704/how-to-get-inline-results-in-a-worksheet-in-eclipse-scala-ide-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the scala installation to default version solved the problem for me.

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on project -> Properties -> Scala Compiler
2. Click the drop down against Scala Installation.
3. Change the value in drop down to "Latest 2.12 bundle (dynamic)"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you write just this It Will write It properly:

```
val hello: String = "Hello World!"
println(hello)
```

Otherwise, you need yo use your object after defining it